# SIGINT lost when output redirected; how to detect termination in program?

Tags: c, linux, sigint

I wrote console program that detects SIGINT, so when user press Ctrl+C program performs some actions and terminates.

But when I redirect this program with pipe to any other, for example: 
`./my_program | tee xxx`
SIGINT never comes to my handler. Despite this program terminates.
Handing SIGTERM gives no effects. SIGTERM does not come after Ctrl+C too.

How can I detect that program is aborted by Ctrl+c in all situations?

---

My test case with SIGINT and SIGPIPE:

```
    #include <csignal>
#include <cstdio>

bool break_request=false;
bool term_request=false;

extern "C" void break_handler(int)
{
    break_request=true;
    printf("Ctrl+C detected\n");
}

extern "C" void term_handler(int)
{
    term_request=true;
    printf("pipe detected\n");
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT,break_handler);
    signal(SIGPIPE,term_handler);

    while(true)
    {
        if(break_request)
        {
            printf("break request handled\n");
            break;
        }

        if(term_request)
        {
            printf("pipe request handled\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("terminating\n");
}
```

Comment: Well, Ctrl-C will only signal the last program, i.e. `tee`. At best, `my_program` gets a SIGPIPE because the reading end of the pipe got closed.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you may get `SIGPIPE` if the program on the other side of the pipe dies. Try setting it to `SIG_IGN` or handle it the same way.

Comment: Classically, the interrupt would be sent to all programs in a pipeline.  I'm not sure if/when the definition of where signals should go has changed, but I have had problems with some simple scripts not dying when I wanted them too — which was both surprising and (extremely) annoying.  I was using `ksh` rather than `bash`; I haven't worked out how much of a factor that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `printf` output is going down the pipe.  Use `fprintf(stderr, "...")` instead.

Comment: But I'm not going to force SIGPIPE event. I want to handle termination in any situation (despite whether program has anything to print at the moment or not)

Comment: No, it is the output that shows you that the signal handler caught the signal that is getting lost in the pipe.  Ctrl-c really is being caught. Try it.

Comment: Got it! You are great! So solution is not to use stdout after SIGINT.
Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

If your program is used in a pipe, it will get `SIGPIPE` if it writes when there's no reader on the other side.

Just install a `SIGPIPE` handler.

Comment: failed.
SIGPIPE handler never called too :(

Comment: Failed probably because program does not try to output anything at the moment. But program terminates at once after Ctrl+C